# AndroidX API body temperature DataType availability

Tags: android, wear-os, temperature

I was wondering if anyone knew when the temperature sensor will be included in the androidx API to use with the galaxy watch 5 pro for example?

I checked the possible DataTypes but i don't see it there yet.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/services/client/data/DataType

The sensor is supposed to be working for cycle tracking for women using the fitness app but I don't see any developer access to the sensor yet?